# Empty PHP variables

Tags: php, variables, null-test

Is there a better way besides `isset()` or `empty()` to test for an empty variable?

Comment: What is wrong with isset() and empty()?

Comment: I thought I remembered reading about a different method on Coding Horror or another blog but couldn't remember it. I'm not saying something is wrong with isset() or empty(), just trying to poke the brain a bit.

Comment: You have to be careful with `empty()` as it returns `true` for some special values such as the string `"0"`.

Comment: there are other ways, although not really better, for example , `strlen()`

Comment: @Asaph - my bad for the previous comment, I read your post wrong.

Comment: @chad, I totally hit the snooze button and spaced out.  Thanks for waking me up!

Comment: @Asaph Well yes, because it's, by PHP's definition, `empty`. That's because PHP deals a lot with strings, especially POST values, so `0` and `"0"` are regarded as equally empty. It's a rule you just have to learn. If you want more precise control, use `isset` and strictly compare to values **you** regard as empty.

Comment: @dscher: No worries. It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon the context.

`isset()` will ONLY return true when the value of the variable is not `NULL` (and thereby the variable is at least defined).

`empty()` will return true when the value of the variable is deemed to be an "empty" value, typically this means `0`, `"0"`, `NULL`, `FALSE`, `array()` (an empty array) and `""` (an empty string), anything else is not empty.

Some examples

```
FALSE == isset($foo);
TRUE == empty($foo);
$foo = NULL;
FALSE == isset($foo);
TRUE == empty($foo);
$foo = 0;
TRUE == isset($foo);
TRUE == empty($foo);
$foo = 1;
TRUE == isset($foo);
FALSE == empty($foo);
```

Comment: `array()`, i.e. an empty array is also `empty`!

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye out for some of the strange == results you get with PHP though; you may need to use === to get the result you expect, e.g.

```
if (0 == '') {
  echo "weird, huh?\n";
}

if  (0 === '') {
  echo "weird, huh?\n";
} else {
  echo "that makes more sense\n";
}
```

Because 0 is false, and an empty string is false, 0 == '' is the same as FALSE == FALSE, which is true.  Using === forces PHP to check types as well.

Comment: Agreed, use var_dump() on your variable before apply conditional code checks and keep this grid-check in mind: http://www.deformedweb.co.uk/php_variable_tests.php